# Sum Rows at Bottom of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-loc

trying to sum rows for specific columns in pandas.

have:

```
df =

name    age gender  sales   commissions
joe     25  m       100     10
jane    55  f       40      4
```

want:

```
df =
name    age gender  sales   commissions
joe     25  m       100     10
jane    55  f       40      4
            
Total               140     14
```

I've tried this option but it's aggregating everything:

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sum the columns of interest only:

```
## recreate your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['joe','jane'],'age':[25,55],'sales':[100,40],'commissions':[10,4]})

df.loc['Total'] = df[['sales','commissions']].sum()
```

Result:

```
>>> df
       name   age  sales  commissions
0       joe  25.0  100.0         10.0
1      jane  55.0   40.0          4.0
Total   NaN   NaN  140.0         14.0
```

If you don't want the NaN to appear, you can replace them with an empty string: `df = df.fillna('')`

Result:

```
>>> df
       name   age  sales  commissions
0       joe  25.0  100.0         10.0
1      jane  55.0   40.0          4.0
Total              140.0         14.0
```

Comment: thank you. is there a way to drop the NaNs?

Comment: Every entry of the DataFrame has to be filled, but you can replace `NaN` with an empty string so that when you print the DataFrame, it doesn't display. But you should know that those entries that appear empty, in fact, contain a string object.